# Django 1.3 error with pagination

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to setup the admin site and get this exception in 1.3:

'cannot import name Paginator'

Any ideas what missing here? I have uncommented all the modules under INSTALLED_APPS

thanks
Sunit

Comment: Can you show some code associated with the exception ?

Comment: Are you getting this error on a brand new django project with only the admin / contrib uncommented in `INSTALLED_APPS`? More details will help you out.. Let's see the traceback too.

Answer (score 1):

you can define '`pagination`' in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('pagination')
```

and in *main.py*

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
```

or you can only add '`from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage`' module in *python*

I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

are you importing correctly ?

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//topics/pagination/#example